# Uploaded Image Displaying in Form Data but not File Data in Flask

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

So I'm trying to upload an image inside a form and then submit it to a python server using Flask.

Right now my issue is that the file name is displaying in the form data, but when I call `request.files` I get an `ImmutableDict`, suggesting that the actual image wasn't uploaded, just the name of its file.

**HTML FORM:**

```
  <form action="/workshops/new" method="post">
      <label for=Title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" id="Title" name="Title" minlength="10" size="150" value="{{ workshop_info[1] if workshop_info }}" class="form-control" required>
      <label for="URL">URL</label>
      <input type="text" id="URL" name="URL" minlength=10 tye="url" size="150" value="{{ workshop_info[3] if workshop_info }}" class="form-control" required>
      <label for="Description">Description</label>
      <textarea id="Description" name="Description" class="form-control" rows="10"  required>{{ workshop_info[2] if workshop_info }}</textarea>
      <label for="Image">Image</label>
    <input type="file" id="Image" name="Image" accept="image/*">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit">{{ "Update Workshop" if class_info else "Add Workshop" }}</button>
  </form>
```

**FLASK CODE:**

```
@app.route('/workshops/new', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def workshopspage():
  if request.method == "POST":
    print(request.form)
    print(request.files)
    return redirect('/')
  return render_template("workshop.html")
```

When the request hits, I get the following image in my terminal:

[image]

My guess is that there's something that I'm not specifying correctly in my html form, but beyond the `name` attribute, I'm not sure what else there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form tag.

```
<form action="/workshops/new" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```